# Having problem with square brackets in node glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I am using this package [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)

The problem I'm facing is whenever my path includes square brackets `[]` it's not giving me any file.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
const glob = require('glob')

const path = 'E:/files/Example [Folder] 1'
const files = glob.sync(path + '/**/*', { 
  nobrace: true,
  noext: true
})
```

It's having no issue with parenthesis `()` or curly braces `{}` but square brackets `[]`.

I am using Windows. How can I fix that? Please help!

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of obvious solutions but do the file/folder names need to contain the [ ] characters? While it is totally valid, it seems unconventional.

Comment: shouldn't it be E:// with double slashes?

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a downloader which lets user download files. Some of the folders contain [ ]. So I need a solution.

Comment: @ZhongWang it works with single slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces `[` and `]` have a special meaning like `*`:

> `[...]` Matches a range of characters, similar to a RegExp range. If the first character of the range is ! or ^ then it matches any character not in the range.

So you need to escape them using `\`

```
const glob = require('glob')

const path = 'E:/files/Example \\[Folder\\] 1'
const files = glob.sync(path + '/**/*', { 
  nobrace: true,
  noext: true
})
```

But in your case you are most like lookign for `root` or `cwd`.

> `cwd` the current working directory in which to search. Defaults to `process.cwd()`.

```
const path = 'E:/files/Example [Folder] 1'
const files = glob.sync('**/*', { 
  nobrace: true,
  noext: true,
  cwd: path
})
```

> `root` The place where patterns starting with `/` will be mounted onto. Defaults to `path.resolve(options.cwd, "/")` (`/` on Unix systems, and `C:\` or some such on Windows.)

```
const path = 'E:/files/Example [Folder] 1'
const files = glob.sync('/**/*', { 
  nobrace: true,
  noext: true,
  root: path
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!